# Error using Wildfly10 + Hibernate-Spatial + Postgis

Tags: postgis, database, hibernate-spatial

Hey I have set up a Nominatim Server to geocode my adresses.

Because this all ready has the data I need in a other place I want to connect my Server again this database.

So I tried to set up a persistence context for the nominatim database.

But I got the following error:

```
2017-03-15 16:47:45,936 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    ... 19 more

2017-03-15 16:47:45,988 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) Wed Mar 15 16:47:45 CET 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-03-15 16:47:46,331 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgis/Geometry
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgis/Geometry
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredMethodProperties(JavaXClass.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgis.Geometry from [Module "deployment.geo_server.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 23 more

2017-03-15 16:47:46,341 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "geo_server")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgis/Geometry
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgis/Geometry
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgis.Geometry from [Module \"deployment.geo_server.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]"
    },
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
2017-03-15 16:47:46,344 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "geo_server.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgis/Geometry
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgis/Geometry
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgis.Geometry from [Module \"deployment.geo_server.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]"
    },
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#geo",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.geo_server#nominatim"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

For me it looks like there are two errors.
First: It can't find the dialect
Second: It can't find the class Geometry

My pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>geo-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.0.0.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="geo">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/ds/geo</jta-data-source>
        <class>de.warzok.bachelor.geo.server.model.Stammdaten</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="nominatim">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/ds/nominatim</jta-data-source>
        <class>de.warzok.bachelor.geo.server.model.NominatimPlace</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the Entityclass should be.

```
package de.warzok.bachelor.geo.server.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.postgis.Geometry;
import org.postgis.PGgeometry;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Entity
@Table(name = "place")
public class NominatimPlace {

    private char osm_type;
    private int osm_id;
    @Column(name = "class")
    private String osmClass;
    private String type;
    private HashMap<String, String> name;
    @Column(name = "admin_level")
    private int adminLevel;
    private String housenumber;
    private String street;
    @Column(name = "addr_place")
    private String addrPlace;
    private String isin;
    private String postcode;
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;
    private HashMap<String,String> extratags;
    private Geometry geometry;

    public NominatimPlace() {
    }

    public char getOsm_type() {
        return osm_type;
    }

    public void setOsm_type(char osm_type) {
        this.osm_type = osm_type;
    }

    public int getOsm_id() {
        return osm_id;
    }

    public void setOsm_id(int osm_id) {
        this.osm_id = osm_id;
    }

    public String getOsmClass() {
        return osmClass;
    }

    public void setOsmClass(String osmClass) {
        this.osmClass = osmClass;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(HashMap<String, String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAdminLevel() {
        return adminLevel;
    }

    public void setAdminLevel(int adminLevel) {
        this.adminLevel = adminLevel;
    }

    public String getHousenumber() {
        return housenumber;
    }

    public void setHousenumber(String housenumber) {
        this.housenumber = housenumber;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getAddrPlace() {
        return addrPlace;
    }

    public void setAddrPlace(String addrPlace) {
        this.addrPlace = addrPlace;
    }

    public String getIsin() {
        return isin;
    }

    public void setIsin(String isin) {
        this.isin = isin;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getExtratags() {
        return extratags;
    }

    public void setExtratags(HashMap<String, String> extratags) {
        this.extratags = extratags;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }
}
```

It seems there aren't much examples and documentation for this. So any help would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around for solutions. Christian gave me a helpful link at the hibernate hip chat.

According to the documentation wildfly seems to provide the jars at the wrong place. Below are some helpful links.

I found a example at https://github.com/dzolo/wildfly-arquillian-hibernate-spatial-postgis which seems to work.

Finaly Christian gave me this link https://avolpe.github.io/hibernate/2016/06/17/wildfly-10-hibernate-spatial.html which did the trick. Now the Server starts without errors.